# Запретить копирования объекта

Tags: c++

```
class B {
   ...
}

class A {
   ...
   std::map<string, B *> ;m
   void setList(std::map<string, B *> &m) {
       this->m = m; //!
   }
}

//main
std::map<string, B *> m;
//заполняем значениями.
a->setList(m);
//дальше очистка l (сначала вызов delete для каждого элемента, а затем clear)
```

Собственно проблема в следующем.

Если внутри класса A вызвать delete для элемента m, то в конце мы его для этого элемента вызвать уже не можем, т.к там указатель. А вот если мы внутри класса A вызовем this->m.clear(), то мы все равно можем вызвать clear и поза классом. Грубо говоря в этом случаи указатели скопировались так, как копируются указатели, а map просто перекопировался как всегда. Правильно?

Как же мне запретить вот это копирования мапа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не можете.

У `map<K, V>` есть операция копирования, поэтому если уж вы можете создать `map`, то его можно будет и скопировать.

Если вы хотите запретить копировать экземпляры класса `A`, вы можете объявить его конструктор копирования приватным. В новых версиях C++ вы можете его просто [удалить](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor#Deleted_implicitly-declared_copy_constructor).

Если вы не хотите, чтобы кто-то мог менять ваш экземпляр `map`, *не отдавайте* ему этот экземпляр. Отдайте, например, копию.

Если получатель `map`'а под вашим контролем, просто положите в качестве правила, что он не является *владельцем* `map`'а, а ыначит, не должен (и не имеет права!) уничтожать его в своём деструкторе.

---

Update:

Исходя из вашего комментария, объект класса `A` не должен являться владельцем `map`'а, а значит, и не должен его удалять в деструкторе.

Проще всего передавать ему на вход объект как read-only в конструкторе, и запоминать не копию объекта (копировать большой `map` дорого), а ссылку на него:

```
class A
{
    const std::map<string, B *>& m;

  public:
    A(const std::map<string, B *>& m) : m(m)
    {
        // empty
    }
};
```

Это — правильный подход, так как без `map` объект всё равно недееспособен, а значит, должен требовать обязательной передачи ему `map`.

Если вам всё же надо уметь передавать `map` *после* того, как объект сконструирован, передавайте по указателю на `const`:

```
class A
{
    const std::map<string, B *>* pm;

  public:
    void setA(const std::map<string, B *>* pm)
    {
        this->pm = pm;
    }
};
```

В обоих случаях, в деструкторе удалять `map` или чистить его не нужно, это задача того кода, который создаёт `map` и наполняет его данными.

Comment: @VladD так экземпляры на класс A и так не будут скопированы (просто через указатели). А вот ключи будут.... Так я и передаю им копию просто другая функция должна использовать вот этот мап. Получатель мапа под моим контролем. Но clear() я могу вызвать дважды, а хотелось бы только один.

Comment: @andrey3: Тогда вопрос: кто является **владельцем** этого `map`'а? Если ни один из экземпляров класса не является (а так оно наверное и есть), то и не им нужно вызывать `clear`.

Или может быть я неправильно понял ваш дизайн. Расскажите о смысле: что делают классы `A` и `B`, для чего нужен `map`?

Comment: @VladD я только тренируюсь. Дизайн класса такой http://pastebin.com/M96P9J15

Comment: @andrey3: Не, это не дизайн. Вы объясните смысл, в терминах предметной области. Это Кошка и Котёнок? Это Машина и Водитель? Это Покупатель и Товары? Имея просто `A` и `B`, невозможно установить, кто за что несёт ответственность.

Comment: @VladD да дизайна толком никакого нет. просто тренируюсь. Вообщем есть мап каких-то указателей, пусть это будут указатели на информацию о человеке. А ключи - это имена людей. Класс А ищет информацию о человеке по параметру переданном в get(). Пусть get() еще проводит реверсирования имени... вообщем еще как-то обрабатывает текст и возвращает указатель на объект информации. Также замечу, что это могут быть не указатели, а опять строки (ключ - имя, значения - фамилия). В этом случаи произойдет полное копирования при передаче в set(), а я хочу избежать этого. Внутри A map меняться не будет.

Comment: @andrey3: понял, обновил ответ.

Comment: @VladD пробую 1 пример, где передача в конструкторе. Вроде бы на том месте ошибок не возникает, но ошибки в конструкторе копирования и операторе присваивания. В частности в конструкторе копирования "требуется инициализация в списке инициализации базовых классов и членов". Эту ошибку я исправил по примеру с nullptr. Но в операторе присваивания невозможно присвоить "ошибка: C2678: бинарный "=": не найден оператор, принимающий левый операнд типа "const QList<T>"
А существует вариант, когда с оператора присваивания вызывается конструктор копирования, тогда бы удалось избежать такой ошибки?

Comment: @andrey3: Если у вас кроме этого ещё есть и оператор присваивания, то так не пойдёт, вам нужно хранить указатель, а не ссылку, т. к. ссылку нельзя «переставить» на другой объект. То есть, вам нужен второй вариант. Можно по идее в конструкторе принимать тоже указатель, если хотите.

Answer (score 2):

Не понимаю про какое копирование вы говорите, у вас  будет скопирован указатель на память в которой находится класс B. В main вы выделили под него память. Если вы в main это память удалили, естественно что вам не стоит её удалять в классе A. Хорошой практикой является удаление памяти в том же месте где она была выделена (если в конструкторе класса, то удалить в деструкторе этого же класса; если вв функции , то удалить в этой же функции и т.д.) - позволяет избежать множества ошибок. 
В вашем случае вижу три способа работы:
1.Хранить сам объект B в map - тоесть будет происходить его копирование. Тогда вам нужно будет написать конструктор копирования для класса B, если в этом есть необходимость.
2. Почитать и разобраться со smart_pointers
3. Пересмотреть архитектуру приложения